# Cmake failing to link with OpenImageIO in Clion 2021.2

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I'm having trouble linking the OpenImageIO Library with cmake. Every-time I attempt to compile I'm getting a linker error. This is the sample code I am attempting to compile with Clion

```
#include <memory>
#include <OpenImageIO/imageio.h>

OIIO_NAMESPACE_USING
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    std::string myFile = "Hello.jpg";
    auto out = ImageOutput::create (myFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my cmake file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19.2)
project(Open_Test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED)
find_package(Openimageio REQUIRED )

add_executable(Open_Test main.cpp)

if(Boost_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    message(STATUS "Boost_LIBRARIES: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
    message(STATUS "Boost_VERSION: ${Boost_VERSION}")
    message(${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY})
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()

if(Openimageio_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "OpenImageIO_INCLUDE_DIR: ${OpenImageIO_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    message(STATUS "Openimageio_LIBRARIES: ${OpenImageIO_LIB_DIR}")
    message(STATUS "Openimageio_VERSION: ${Openimageio_VERSION}")
    include_directories(${OpenImageIO_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif()


target_link_libraries(Open_Test
        ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY}
        ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY}
        ${WHAT TO SET IT TOO}
        )
```

I'm pretty sure the problem lies with target_link_libraries. I'm not sure what to put for OpenImageIO. I've tried putting a direct link to the library (/usr/local/Cellar/openimageio/2.2.17.0/lib) and (/usr/local/Cellar/openimageio/2.2.17.0/lib/libOpenImageIO_Util.2.2.17.dylib)

I'm just not very familiar with cmake. Any help is appreciated

Here is the linker error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "OpenImageIO_v2_2::ImageOutput::create(OpenImageIO_v2_2::string_view, OpenImageIO_v2_2::Filesystem::IOProxy*, OpenImageIO_v2_2::string_view)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [Open_Test] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Open_Test.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Open_Test.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Open_Test] Error 2
```

Comment: `message(STATUS "Openimageio_LIBRARIES: ${OpenImageIO_LIB_DIR}")` looks strange.

Comment: I was using that as a debug statement to see where it was locating OpenImageIO. It prints out (/usr/local/Cellar/openimageio/2.2.17.0/lib)

Comment: Do you have the 64 bit version of the library? I would think it would go in /usr/.../lib64? Is your LD_LIBRARY_PATH have that path set? echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: Openimageio_LIBRARIES is not OpenImageIO_LIB_DIR. So, you know these variables and unable to use them in target_link_libraries?

Comment: I just figured it out by accident. I had a typo. libOpenImageIO.2.2.17.dylib not libOpenImageIO_Util.2.2.17.dylib

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was due to a typo inside target_link_library. The directory

```
/usr/local/Cellar/openimageio/2.2.17.0/lib/libOpenImageIO_Util.2.2.17.dylib)
```

needs to be

```
(/usr/local/Cellar/openimageio/2.2.17.0/lib/libOpenImageIO.2.2.17.dylib)
```

Then it works like a champ

```
target_link_libraries(Open_Test /usr/local/Cellar/openimageio/2.2.17.0/lib/libOpenImageIO.2.2.17.dylib)
```